# Could not find element

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following piece of code:

```
if browser.ul(:class => "page-list").present? && browser.ul(:class => "page-list").lis.last.text.to_i > 1
  pages = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(browser.ul(:class => "page-list").html).css("a").map { |link| link.text }
```

The `if` statement gives `true`, but `browser.ul(:class => "page-list")` in the next line returns:

```
unable to locate element, using {:class=>\"page-list\", :tag_name=>\"ul\"}".
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page-nav">
  <a class="prev disabled" onclick="return false" href="#">
    <span><i></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="page-list">
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:submitCustomPagination('page', 2)">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:submitCustomPagination('page', 3)">3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="next" href="javascript:submitCustomPagination('nextPage')">
    <span>Next<i></i>  </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Please explain how this is possible and how to fix it.

Comment: It would perhaps help if you could show the HTML which triggers this error ;-)

Comment: Is the `ul` element being reloaded? For example, you click one of the paging links, check if the `ul` is present, the `ul` starts to be reloaded, you then try to retrieve it again before it has finished reloading?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Justin Ko. No, I click on `ul` elements only after mentioned statements

Answer (score 0):

Potentially something client side is re-rendering the page or the list element (as suggested by Justin Ko in comments).  I can suggest a couple of things you might try to troubleshoot this.

1) enter the code a line at a time in IRB. use IRB to fire up a browser, navigate it manually to the page you want and then copy paste the code into the IRB command line. As this is slower than just running the script, this can expose lots of timing issues, and if you observe carefully you can sometimes see redraws etc.  Typically code that works when executed slower a line at a time in IRB but not within a script is a sign of a timing/sync problem.

2) add some debugging code to watch the state of that element.  between the two lines of code you have, maybe add something like

```
30 times do
  puts "is the page-list present?: #{browser.ul(:class => "page-list").present?}"
  wait .1
end
```

if code like that shows you anything but all trues, then client side javascript may be updating the DOM still